# Transferring the project from "Altium Design" to "SolidWorks" while maintaining silk-screen printing, sizes and everything else

Tags: solidworks, electrical, circuits, drawings

I want to transfer the PCB project to solidwork from altium design, I read forums on how to do it better, and so:

1. Save to STEP. The option is good and working, but I did not like the option, since silk-screen printing and tracks on the PCB are not drawn. The PCB itself is just like a block, very unrealistic. Adding PCB tracks by overlaying a photo is not an option.[image]
2. Save to PDF3D. It also works well, but there are also problems, namely:

1. The board opens in the form of Graphics bodies, if you open it as a solid body or surface, then the solid simply hangs and that's it.
2. The size of the fee changes completely. There should be a length of 100 mm, and it is 9 with something, that is, the point is not in the correct translation of inch-centimeter-meter-millimeter.
3. When drawing, all colors are lost, the board and elements are just gray, although in the working environment the model can be rotated and it is colored. You can manually sit to paint all the conductors and radioelements, set the material for them. Yes, it works, after painting, the model can be drawn very well, but it is long and wrong to sit and paint what I have already painted in another program.

[image]
[image]

Although everything looks great here, for example:
But I need to be sized, not just have a pretty picture.
[image]

3. And the last option, as the most developing one at the present time, is "Collaborating between Altium Designer and SOLIDWORKS". This is the cloud storage of the project. I simply did not manage to do it, it’s something difficult, I need a paid registration and I cannot do it.

the "SOLIDWORKS PCB Add-in" also requires registration and it is very difficult.

It also exists, but it seems to me that this is something old and does not receive development: "Solidworks modeler for Altium"

Comment: You can adjust the size quite easily using the 'scale' tool. Would this help?